# How to enable Gradle DSL support in Eclipse when doing 'gradlew eclipseClean eclipse'

Tags: spring-tool-suite

When I run 'gradlew cleanEclipse eclipse' my project looses the 'Gradle DSL Support' and the 'Dependency Management'. The only way to activate is by hand (Right Click->Gradle->Enable DSL Support), for every project inside Eclipse.

There is a way to do this from the command line? I have a large number of projects and so far I haven't found any information on the [official DSL](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseProject.html) documentation.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly as expected because when you run Gradle command 'cleanEclipse' it wipes out all the eclipse metadata and then 'eclipse' task rewrites it.

However, gradle itself is not aware of the tooling support such as 'DSL enabled' and won't generate the metadata for that.

To avoid this, use 'Refresh All' from the Gradle tool menu in Eclipse itself. This will also execute 'cleanEclipse eclipse' but also reinstate previous settings like DSL support.

I realize this is not really an answer to your question "There is a way to do this from the command line?". You could try only running the 'eclipse' task and not 'cleanEclipse' which is the one that wipes out the metadata.

Also, may be good to point out that DSL support in Gradle STS tooling has been discontinued in STS 3.7.0, so the answer to this question may not be very relevant in the future.

Comment: Any idea why DSL support has been removed? I am looking for that feature :/